# C# wpf adding new row to another data table

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have a product table which has 9 columns, I have another table which I only want to have 4 columns which is why I declared this

```
    private void SetCartColumns()
    {
        cartTable.Columns.Add("Product Code", typeof(Int32));
        cartTable.Columns.Add("Product Name", typeof(String));
        cartTable.Columns.Add("Product Quantity", typeof(Int32));
        cartTable.Columns.Add("Total Price", typeof(double));
    }
```

Now I want to add the selected index or item in my product table to the cart table, and here are the codes

---

```
    private void BtnAddToCart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dtgProducts.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is no selected rows!");// show a message here to inform
        }
        else
        {
            while (dtgProducts.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedIndex = dtgProducts.SelectedIndex;
                var selectedRows = ((DataRow)searchTable.Rows[selectedIndex]);
                int code = selectedRows.Field<int>(("Code"));
                string name = selectedRows.Field<string>(("Name"));
                int quan = selectedRows.Field<int>(("Quantity"));
                float price = selectedRows.Field<float>(("Price"));
                double totalPrice = Convert.ToDouble(price);


                cartTable.Rows.Add(new Object[] { code, name, quan, totalPrice });
            }
            dtgCart.ItemsSource = cartTable.AsDataView();
        }
    }
```

---

but whenever I am clicking the add to cart button, nothing happens but instead my program hangs and I cant click on anything aside from stopping the debugging.. would someone show me how to add new item to a new table with selected columns only

Comment: Can you post the xaml of your DataGrid. You shouldn't need to do this much work in your code behind to control your DataGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx

And you should avoid having space in the column name of the dataTable